# WPF DataGrid Display Issue In Windows XP

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, windows-xp

Can any one help me...

1)

### Problem -->

|***Name*__**|*Address****_*_**|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____<---DataGrid Header
|------------------------------------------------------------------- <--Rows
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
|-------------------------------------------------------------------

rows getting cutted.

2)

### Want this->

|***Name*__**|**__*Address*__*_*_**|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___*<---DataGrid Header
|*_ABC_*_*|***XYZ***__*_*__*_*__*|****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

|**_*AHJ*__**|**XZS_*_*__*_*__*_***|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____

|**_*ALK*__**|**XYF_*_*__*_*__*_***|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____
can see row detail.

i am having trouble some of the rows are not displaying properly in windows xp,
this program is build in Win 8, WPF .net framework 4.0,3.5,4.5.
all of them having same issue.

Am i missing something?
how to solve this.

WPF DataGrid,has auto generatedcolumn = true.

here is some code.
XAML

```
      <DataGrid x:Name="dgConfirmInquiry" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" Width="718" Background="#FFF0FFE3"  AutoGeneratingColumn="dgInquiry_AutoGeneratingColumn" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="dgInquiry_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="dgInquiry_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuRegister" Header="Register" Click="MenuRegister_Click" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        </DataGrid>
```

at code behind i am just filling itemsource of DataGrid with List.
on windows 7,8 i am not having this issue.
this only happening in Windows XP.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you manually set the columns?

Comment: Can you provide actual pictures showing the problem? I have a hard time figuring out your char diagram - they don't seem to correlate with each other...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting values for margins and possibly height and width too. Windows XP treats this differently to windows 7/8 and so displays it differently.

You should remove these xaml attributes and you can use alternative methods for positioning and sizing, such as placing the datagrid into a grid cell and setting width via the Grid.ColumnDefinitions and height via Grid.RowDefinitions. Then use vertical and horizontal alignment for setting margins (which is relative to the grid cell). You can then assign the datagrid to a margin via its Grid.Column and Grid.Row attributes.

Let me know if you need an example and I'll update this accordingly.